# How can I remove blank space in my Eclipse plug-in?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm beginner for Eclipse plug-in development.

I had developed some Eclipse plug-in using Nebula that provide extended view component such as graphs, table, etc.

I wanna draw three components in the view (using MeterFigure, List of SWT, XYGraph).

However, when I created three components, there is blank in the view!

So, I inspect my code, but I couldn't find where is problem.

This is capture of blank (see the space between figure and text).
[image]

This is code for creating three components.

```
@Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        ...
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, true);
        parent.setLayout(layout);
        parent.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.GRAB_VERTICAL));

        merterFigure = new merterFigureClass(parent, SWT.NONE);
        GridData gridData = new GridData();
        gridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
        gridData.verticalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
        gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
        gridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
        merterFigure.setLayoutData(gridData);

        list = new ListClass(parent, SWT.NONE);
        gridData = new GridData();
        gridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
        gridData.verticalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
        gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
        gridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
        list.setLayoutData(gridData);
        list.initialize();

        graph = new GraphClass(parent, SWT.NONE);
        gridData = new GridData();
        gridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
        gridData.verticalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
        gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
        gridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
        graph.setLayoutData(gridData);

        list.setGraph(graph);
    }
```

This is MeterFigureClass.

```
public class MeterFigureClass extends Canvas {
        private MeterFigure meterFigure;

        public MeterFigureClass(Composite parent, int style) {
            super(parent, style);

            LightweightSystem lws = new LightweightSystem(this);
            meterFigure = new MeterFigure();
            meterFigure.setBackgroundColor(XYGraphMediaFactory.getInstance().getColor(255, 255, 255));
            meterFigure.setValueLabelVisibility(true);
            meterFigure.setRange(0, 100);
            meterFigure.setLoLevel(35);
            meterFigure.setLoloLevel(20);
            meterFigure.setHiLevel(85);
            meterFigure.setHihiLevel(70);
            meterFigure.setMajorTickMarkStepHint(80);

            lws.setContents(readabilityScore);
        }

        public void setValue(double value) {
            this.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    meterFigure.setValue(value);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

This is ListClass.

```
public class ListClass extends Canvas {
        private org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List list;
        private List<Data> dataList;
        private GraphClass graph;

        public ListClass(Composite parent, int style) {
            super(parent, style);

            list = new org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List(parent, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
            dataList = new ArrayList<Data>();

            ...

            GridData gridData = new GridData();
            gridData.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
            gridData.verticalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
            list.setLayoutData(gridData);

        }

        ....

        public void setGraph(GraphClass Graph) {
            this.Graph = Graph;
        }

        ....
    }
```

This is GraphClass.

```
ublic class MatrixGraph extends Canvas {
    private char count;
    private XYGraph matrixGraph;
    private LightweightSystem lws;

    public MatrixGraph(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
        addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
            @Override
            public void paintControl(org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintEvent e) {
                MatrixGraph.this.paintControl(e);
            }
        });
    }

    public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
        if (count < 1)
            count++;
        else {
            lws = new LightweightSystem(this);

            matrixGraph = new XYGraph();

            setGraphProperties();

        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `GridData` layout you are specifying:

```
    gridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
```

This is telling the layout to grab as much vertical space as possible even though it may only be blank. Since you are specifying this for multiple controls the extra space is divided between the controls.

If you don't want the blank space use

```
gridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = false;
```

or just omit this as it is the default.

Also try not using FILL for the vertical alignment, TOP would probably be better:

```
gridData.verticalAlignment = SWT.TOP;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. For your answer i tried your answer, but it still remain. it just decrease size of blank space....

Comment: Try changing the vertical alignment as well - see updated answer. I don't have all the things you are using installed so I can't test this. But you need to learn more about GridLayout and look at the layout of every component.

Comment: Hmm... thank you for advice. I'll start studying GridLayout. And, in my version of GridData, there is no TOP attribute. The version of library is 3.105.0. Can you recommend me the web sitet for studying GridLayout?

Comment: Sorry that should be SWT.TOP (or GridData.BEGINNING). [Understanding Layouts in SWT](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm) is the standard article on starting with layouts.

Comment: Hmmm.... I use GridData.BeGINNING and SWT.TOP now. However, It has same problem. So, i visit the site you recommended, i'll try any solution. Thank you for your favor.